# How does the contact pad used with Duracell myGrid mat work?

Tags: power, connector

[Duracell myGrid](http://www.duracell.com/en-US/category/mygrid.jspx) puzzles me. It's a charging system consisting of a base pad where devices with special contact pads (called Power Sleeve or Power Clip) are placed for charging.

The base pad surface is covered in parallel metal stripes connected to the power source such that even pads are positive terminals and odd pads are negative terminals. The device to charge is equipped with a matching pad that has four small edge contacts projecting downwards and [aligned in star pattern](http://www.duracell.com/en-US/series/mygrid-accessories.jspx) such that however the device is positioned on the pad there exist at least two contacts that connect to different stripes on the base pad. This is guaranteed by following the right proportions between the stripes widths and the distances between the contacts on the device pad. So however the device is positioned on the pad it gets connected to both a positive and a negative base terminal and receives power for charging.

The latter is what puzzles me. How is such contact pad (the one of the device) designed that it allows up to three contacts to be connected to the same terminal and no matter which fourth contact is connected to the opposite terminal the device is being powered correctly regardless of how the device is positioned on the base pad?

Comment: somewhat related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/93924/7036

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not seen the circuitry used (or even seen a Mygrid device) but it almost certainly works by having two diodes from each Mygrid contact point to the internal power circuit in the device being charged.

- One diode per contact connects with its Anode to the contact and its Cathode to the accessory "+ve" connection  (ie the diode "arrow" points from contact to accessory +) . This diode conducts when a Mygrid +ve terminal is encountered.
- One diode per contact connects with its Cathode connected to the Mygrid contact and its Anode to accessory "-ve" connection (ie the diode "arrow" points from accessory towards the Mygrid device. This diode conducts when a Mygrid -ve terminal is encountered.

This way, whatever polarity is on the contact will be correctly routed to the accesory.

Comment: Kind of like a de-constructed bridge rectifier.

Comment: @Majenko - It's a multi-phase rectifier, of which a bridge rectifier is one type (for single phase).

Comment: OR a single phase rectifier with 4 input connections :-).